# How make correctly time with DateFormat

Tags: flutter

I ran into a problem. I made a chat where the time of sending the message is shown, but the time that is shown does not coincide with the current time. I live in Kazakhstan. The screenshot shows the difference.

[image]

This is code

```
DateFormat.yMd().format(message.createdAt) + " " + DateFormat.Hm().format(message.createdAt)
```

Also, data are taken from firebase.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the Android emulator/device timezone the same as your machines timezone?

Try checking in the Android emulator/device.

I believe it's under System > Date & Time > Time zone

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [LINK](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

or
Write below code for testing what you want see on output:

```
print(DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.now()));
```

Comment: is there another way? I'm just taking data from firebase. The time in the database shows normally, but for some reason it shows a completely different time in futter.